# Set default value to select element

Tags: angular

I want to set a default value to the dropdown. The default value should be the first element.

```
    <select  id="myfrm" formControlName="size" required>

       <option *ngFor="let size of size.num" value={{size.id}}>
         {{size.value}}
       </option>
   </select>
```

Comment: It's still just plain HTML5, add the `selected` attribute to whichever option needs to be the default selection.

Answer (score 0):

Bind `selected` property of `options` to set default selection.

Example: `[selected]="selectedValue === size.value"`

```
<option  
  *ngFor="let size of size.num" 
  [selected]="selectedValue === size.value" 
  value={{size.id}}
>
    {{size.value}}
 </option>
```

Stackblitz Snippet:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o7lpgw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: How to select the first option as the default option in the dropdown. According to your example it is setting the last option as default.

Comment: First one always get selected if you don't mention anything. Let me know if i missing your any point